# Collect lightning energy

Tags: physics, energy, lightning

Lightning is an abundant source of energy.It is clean,huge and renewable.Is there any way to collect the energy from lighting,store it and reuse later?

Answer (score 5):

[Many have tried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy), but no-one has had much success.

Problem is, even if they *were* successful, lightning strikes are, for most places, relatively rare and unpredictable. You'd need to invest in a lot of power storage capacity (expensive, bulky, not maintenance free, inefficiency causes losses on charging and discharging) and even then you'd need to have some other sources of power to get you going and tide you over any dry spells.

Furthermore, whilst the energy delivered by a single lightning strike is relatively high (gigajoules) you can get as much power out of a normal power station in relatively short order, and continuously. The total energy in a storm might be very high, but it will be distributed over quite a wide geographic area as the storm moves, so you'd need to distribute your harvesting and storage and distribution systems across very wide areas in the hopes that a storm will head that way, one day.

All in all, it seems like an awful lot of effort, for relatively little reward compared to conventional power sources, renewable or otherwise.

Comment: As a direct comparison of energy output, a lightning bolt might contain 5000 MJ of energy, while a typical coal power plant might output 500 MW (500 MJ per second) - the power plant produces a lightning bolt's worth of energy every 10 seconds, every day for years on end, regardless of the weather.

Answer (score 2):

The halfbakery has many lightning harnessing schemes for your reading pleasure.

One of the more practical is linked here: harvest the charge from the sky before it builds up to the point that it can break down the air into plasma and arc to earth as a giant spark.

https://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Lightning_20Rod_20Power_20Generation#1272673926

> Use a kite or a balloon to carry aloft a lightning rod. The tether for
>   the kite or balloon would be made of something lightweight,
>   electrically conducting, and electrically insulated. The rod would, of
>   course, be connected to the conductor in the tether. At ground level,
>   the voltage difference between the tether's conductor and the earth is
>   used to generate usable electricity.

A more in depth exploration of the execution of this idea is found in the discussion section of this (sort of lame) linked idea.

http://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Lightning_20Power_20Plant

> SOLUTION: Ballons with an aluminized skin floated into different
>   locations of the storm, secured to the ground with conductive cables.
>   Since the potential energy in the opposing clouds is d.c. until a
>   lightning strike occurs, power may be simply tapped from the two
>   opposing ballon cables by using an auto-polarity d.c to d.c converter
>   designed to handle an input voltage of say 5-10,000 volts. The output
>   of the converter may be made to be 60hz sine wave AC (synchronized to
>   and fed into a power grid) or low voltage d.c to charge batteries. In
>   the event that the atmospheric voltage starts to increase above the
>   maximum input of the converter, the two cables from the balloons are
>   loaded through power resistors or shunted together, regulating the
>   input voltage to the converter below its limit and well below the
>   voltage required for any lightning strike. This method also eliminates
>   losses due to radiation of energy in RF, IR and visible wavelengths --
>   providing very large amounts of harnessable power without the need to
>   harness the lightning bolt itself.

Comment: Looking at the grounding straps for lightning conductors in my neighbourhood, I'm not seeing anything I'd describe as "lightweight"...

Comment: @StarfishPrime  The lightning rods in your neighborhood are built in anticipation of a strike.  The collecting balloons would instead try to gradually siphon off collecting charge, preventing a strike.  I am sure that from time to time one of these balloon / wire apparati would turn into a conduit for a lightning bolt, so you would want them dispensable too.